# PHP Linter for Gulp with Rules file?

Tags: php, eslint, rules, lint, software-quality

Is there a NPM Gulp module that can not only `lint` my PHP code, but has a config/rules file that would allow me to specify certain things such as:

- Classes open with `{` on next line
- All methods must have correct DocType
- etc.

I use an ESLinter for my JS code that works really nice. It has a `.eslintrc` file where I specify all my rules. Kinda like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "indent": [ 2, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1} ],
    "linebreak-style": [ 2, "unix" ],
    "eol-last": 1,
    "no-multi-spaces": 1,
    "quotes": [ 1, "single", "avoid-escape" ],
    "semi": [ 2, "always" ],
    "array-bracket-spacing": [ 1, "always", { "objectsInArrays": false } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) tool.